# how to remove margin between the buttons?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, ionic-framework

I am making tab bar on top of my screen .I need to give equal width to all my buttons .But I take a row and inside that I take three columns but button is  is not taking  all width as column why ? could you please tell me how to take whole width as  shown in image

here is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGqgYg

```
[![<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <ion-view ng-controller="vroCtrl">
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content class="padding">
           <div class="" id="buttonTab">
          <div class="button_vro_bar row">
            <div class="col"><a class="button " ng-click="handlerButtonClick('FY16_18_design')"
               ng-class="{'button_active':activeContentArea==='FY16_18_design'}">FY16 -18 Design (vs Target)</a></div>
            <div class="col"><a class="button " ng-click="handlerButtonClick('key_design_health')"
               ng-class="{'button_active':activeContentArea==='key_design_health'}">Key Design health Indicators</a></div>
            <div class="col"><a class="button " ng-click="handlerButtonClick('hc_swb')"
               ng-class="{'button_active':activeContentArea==='hc_swb'}">HC & SWB</a></div>


          </div>

        </div>

        <div ng-if="activeContentArea=='FY16_18_design'">
          <h1>FY16_18_design</h1>

        </div>
        <div ng-if="activeContentArea=='key_design_health'">
          <h1>key_design_health</h1>
        </div>

        <!-- account detail -->
        <div id="wrapper" ng-if="activeContentArea=='hc_swb'">
          <h1>hc_swb</h1>


        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Update**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGqgYg using width :inherit  i solve my problem ..but how to remove margin how to remove marigin  between columns

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGqgYg using width :inherit  i solve my problem ..but how to remove margin how to remove marigin  between columns

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the white space between those divs. [Reference](http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block)

Answer (score 0):

**Codepin** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/epNEda?editors=110

All thats needed is to add a custom class

```
.no-padding{
 padding:0!important;
}
```

and add it to your `.col` `divs`.

***edit***

New **Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/QjbMdV?editors=110

This is if you want it to fit 100% of the page with no spacing

Answer (score 0):

Just add a CSS rule to overwrite ionic default style :

```
.col{
  padding:0 !important;
}
```

[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKaqjE)